# A Mapping of Primes

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

Recently, I have found a bijective mapping \$f\$ from positive integers to finite, nested sequences. The purpose of this challenge is to implement it in the language of your choice.

### The Mapping

Consider a number \$n\$ with the factors \$2^{a_1}3^{a_2}5^{a_3}\cdots p^{a_i}\$ where \$a_i > 0\$

$$f(n) = \{f(a_2+1),f(a_3+1),\cdots,f(a_i+1),\underbrace{\{\},\{\},\cdots,\{\}}_{a_1}\}$$

For example:

$$\begin{align} f(22308) & = \{f(2),f(1),f(1),f(2),f(3),\{\},\{\}\} \\
& = \{\{\{\}\},\{\},\{\},\{\{\}\},\{f(2)\},\{\},\{\}\} \\
& = \{\{\{\}\},\{\},\{\},\{\{\}\},\{\{\{\}\}\},\{\},\{\}\}
\end{align}$$

### Rules

- You may write a full program or a function to do this task.
- Output can be in any format recognisable as a sequence.
- Built-ins for prime factorization, primality testing, etc. are **allowed**.
- Standard loopholes are disallowed.
- Your program must complete the last test case in under 10 minutes on my machine.
- This is code-golf, so the shortest code wins!

### Test Cases

- `10`: `{{},{{}},{}}`
- `21`: `{{{}},{},{{}}}`
- `42`: `{{{}},{},{{}},{}}`
- `30030`: `{{{}},{{}},{{}},{{}},{{}},{}}`
- `44100`: `{{{{}}},{{{}}},{{{}}},{},{}}`
- `16777215`: `{{{{}}},{{}},{{}},{},{{}},{{}},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{{}}}`
- `16777213`: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/28MmezyT)

Comment: Is the same output, without the commas, still *recognisable as a sequence*?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, you can tell by the brackets.

Comment: How about the number 1

Comment: Ooh, that is {}.

Comment: Would [this](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmkoTGF7KW1mX1c9KXttcH0sXGZlPSgwYSore2p9JX1qcA&input=MTY3NzcyMTU) be an acceptable output format? CJam doesn't distinguish between empty lists and empty strings, so this is the natural way of representing a nested array.

Comment: @Dennis I can accept that, I just didn't want people outputting things like `83e3b5d246e61bd0` and saying that it is a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÓćÅ0«ε¯sF¸
```

Output with `[]` instead of `{}`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9vc2FiaWX//8OTxIfDhTDCq861wq9zRsK4//8yMjMwOA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w5OPtB9uNTi0@tzWQ@uL3Q7t@F9bq/M/2sjI2MBCx9BAx8hQx8RIx9jAwNhAx8TE0MBAx9DM3NzcyNAUKGtgqQOU0zHVMdcxNNQxNI4FAA), where test case `16777213` is replaced with `1009` (another prime number) - the output for `16777213` would be similar, just with *a lot* more leading `[],` ..

**Explanation:**

```python
Ó           # Get the exponents of the prime factorization of the (implicit) input
            #  ([a,b,c,d,...] in 2^a*3^b*5^c*7^d*...=input)
 ć          # Extract head; pop and push remainder-list and first item separated
  Å0        # Get a list of 0s with a length equal to the `a` exponent
    «       # Merge that as trailing items to the remainder-list
     ε      # Map over each integer in the list:
      ¯     #  Push an empty list
       s    #  Swap so the current number is at the top of the stack
        F   #  Loop that many times
         ¸  #   And wrap the list into a list every iteration
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: wow, that is *really* short.

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, <s>51</s> <s>48</s> <s>44</s> <s>42</s> <s>41</s> <s>39</s> <s>34</s> <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
{mf_W=)1|{mp},\fe=(0a*+{)J}%}:J
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%0A%20%20%7Bmf_W%3D)1%7C%7Bmp%7D%2C%5Cfe%3D(0a*%2B%7B)J%7D%25%7D%3AJ%0A~%60&input=16777215).

*Thanks to @MartinBüttner for golfing off 3 bytes!*

*Thanks to @PeterTaylor for golfing off 3 bytes and paving the way for 1 more!*

At least on my computer, downloading the file takes longer than running the program...

#### I/O

This is a named function that pops and integer from STDIN and pushes an array in return.

Since CJam does not distinguish between empty arrays and empty strings – a string is simply a list that contains only characters –, the string representation will look like this:

```
[[""] "" [""] ""]
```

referring to the following, nested array

```
[[[]] [] [[]] []]
```

#### Verification

```
$ wget -q pastebin.com/raw.php?i=28MmezyT -O test.ver
$ cat prime-mapping.cjam
ri
  {mf_W=)1|{mp},\fe=(0a*+{)J}%}:J
~`
$ time cjam prime-mapping.cjam <<< 16777213 > test.out

real    0m25.116s
user    0m23.217s
sys     0m4.922s
$ diff -s <(sed 's/ //g;s/""/{}/g;y/[]/{}/' < test.out) <(tr -d , < test.ver)
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 are identical
```

#### How it works

```
{                           }:J  Define a function (named block) J.
 mf                              Push the array of prime factors, with repeats.
   _W=                           Push a copy and extract the last, highest prime.
      )1|                        Increment and OR with 1.
         {mp},                   Push the array of primes below that integer.

                                 If 1 is the highest prime factor, this pushes
                                 [2], since (1 + 1) | 1 = 2 | 1 = 3.
                                 If 2 is the highest prime factor, this pushes
                                 [2], since (2 + 1) | 1 = 3 | 1 = 3.
                                 If p > 2 is the highest prime factor, it pushes
                                 [2 ... p], since (p + 1) | 1 = p + 2, where p + 1
                                 is even and, therefor, not a prime.

              \fe=               Count the number of occurrences of each prime
                                 in the factorization.

                                 This pushes [0] for input 1.

                  (              Shift out the first count.
                   0a*           Push a array of that many 0's.
                      +          Append it to the exponents.

                                 This pushes [] for input 1.

                       {  }%     Map; for each element in the resulting array:
                                   Increment and call J.
```

Comment: Blame Pastebin :P

Comment: `mf e=` is much better than what I'd found when I knocked up a sanity test while the question was in the sandbox, but one improvement I found which you haven't used is to do the mapping for the twos as `(0a*+` - i.e. `ri{}sa2*{mf_W=){mp},\fe=(0a*+0j\{)j}%*}j`. And there's a much bigger improvement as well which I'll give you a few hours' headstart on...

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for the golf and the hint.

Comment: Yep, changing the output representation was indeed the bigger improvement. There's a better way of handling the base case too, which I've only just found, but to beat your solution I have to use two of your ideas so: `{mf_W=)1|{mp},\fe=(0a*+{)J}%}:J`

Comment: @PeterTaylor That one magical `1|`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 88 bytes

```
f@1={};f@n_:=f/@Join[1+{##2},1&~Array~#]&@@SparseArray[PrimePi@#->#2&@@@FactorInteger@n]
```

Comment: The magic of undocumented internals...

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
ÆEµ“”WẋḢ;@‘ß€$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm@uhrY8a5jxqmBv@cFf3wx2LrB0eNcw4PP9R0xqV/4fbgdTRSQ93zgDSkWCF0bFAoroWqB6o29BAR8HIUEfBxAhIGxkbWOgoGBsYGANFTUwMDYCUoZm5ubmRoSkA)

The last test case times out on TIO. The Footer runs the program over the inputs, gets their raw form (Jelly doesn't display empty lists well) and replaces the `[]` with `{}`

### How it works

```
ÆEµ“”WẋḢ;@‘ß€$ - Main link. Takes n on the left
ÆE             - Compute the prime exponents of n
  µ            - Begin a new link with the exponents E as the argument
   “”          - []
     W         - [[]]
       Ḣ       - Take the first exponent, a
      ẋ        - Repeat each element of [[]] a times
             $ - Group the previous 2 links as a monad f(E):
          ‘    -   Increment each exponent
            €  -   Over each:
           ß   -     Recursively run the main link
        ;@     - Append the [[]] to the recursive call result
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 29 bytes

```
L+'MhMtbmYhbL&JPby/LJf}TPTSeJ
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%2B%27MhMtbmYhbL%26JPby%2FLJf%7DTPTSeJ%27Q&input=16777215&debug=0)

This defines a function, `'`, which performs the desired mapping.

A helper function, `y`, performs the mapping recursively given a prime decomposition. The base case and the prime decomposition are performed in `'`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 34 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ÑE│♂█ⁿt2N╔₧Ñ↓Ls&ûΦ}eóâÇΔ-ë╖»8Kq+╔r
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a545b30bdbfc74324ec99ea5194c732696e87d65a28380ff2d89b7af384b712bc972&i=10%0A21%0A42&m=2)

There's very likely a better way to do this with recursion, but I just can't seem to find anything related to it in the builtin docs. So, this is a manually built implementation.

Takes very, very long after the third test case.

### Explanation (Unpacked)

```
z]Yx{c2>{|nBs{y@msz]s|*+c]ys+Yd}{vy@}?F|u
z]                                        array [[]]
  Y                                       write that to register Y
   x{                                 F   for i in [1..input]
     c2>                                  if i < 2,
                                {vy@}     increment and take element at that index from y
        {|n                               otherwise take prime exponents
           Bs                             push the first element and the rest of the array separately
             {  m                         map the rest of the array to:
              y@                          elements in y at those indices
                 sz]s                     push [[]] and first element
                     |*                   repeat it's elements that many times
                       +                  add those together
                        c]ys+Y            and append that to register Y
                              d}          then delete it
                                       |u convert the last element on stack to string
                                          implicit output
```