# Map a list of indefinite size to a number!

Tags: code-golf, set-theory, open-ended-function

It is well known, in the field of Mathematics studying infinity, that [the Cartesian product of any finite amount of countable sets is also countable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable/Corollary).

Your task is to write two programs to implement this, one to map from list to integer, one to map from integer to list.

Your function must be bijective and deterministic, meaning that `1` will always map to a certain list, and `2` will always map to another certain list, etc...

[Earlier](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71924/bijective-mapping-from-integers-to-a-variable-number-of-bits), we mapped integers to a list consisting only of `0` and `1`.

**However, now the list will consist of non-negative numbers.**

## Specs

- Program/function, reasonable input/output format.
- Whether the mapped integers start from `1` or starts from `0` is your choice, meaning that `0` doesn't have to (but may) map to anything.
- The empty array `[]` must be encoded.
- Input/output may be in any base.
- Sharing code between the two functions is **allowed**.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Lowest score wins.

Score is the sum of lengths (in bytes) of the two programs/functions.

Comment: "However, now the list will consist of non-negative numbers."

Comment: So, to be clear, we're mapping `N^inf -> N`?

Comment: @Mego N^inf is not countable. N^k where k is any finite number is.

Comment: We have been discussing about this in chat.

Comment: *Whether it starts from 1 or starts from 0 is your choice.* Does that apply to the single integer and to the integers in the list.

Comment: Are two functions allowed, rather than two programs?

Comment: @Dennis Clarified.

Comment: @Mego Clarified.

Comment: If two functions are posted, may they interact with each other? I'm asking since some languages have a built-in function inverse.

Comment: @Dennis It is allowed.

Comment: Related: [Pack sequences of non-negative integers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26562)

Comment: Related:[A Mapping of Primes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64555)

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>18</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

#### List to integer, <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
TṪạL;³ÆẸ
```

Maps lists of non-negative integers to positive integers. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=VOG5quG6oUw7wrPDhuG6uA&input=&args=WzAsIDEsIDIsIDMsIDBd)

#### Integer to list, 8 bytes

```
ÆE©Ḣ0ẋ®;
```

Maps positive integers to lists of non-negative integers . [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4ZFwqnhuKIw4bqLwq47&input=&args=NjUyMTkw)

### Background

Let **p<sub>0</sub>, p<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>2</sub>, ⋯** be the sequence of prime numbers in ascending order.

For each list of non-negative integers **A := [a<sub>1</sub>, ⋯, a<sub>n</sub>]**, we map **A** to **p<sub>0</sub><sup>z(A)</sup>p<sub>1</sub><sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup>⋯p<sub>n</sub><sup>a<sub>n</sub></sup>**, where **z(A)** is the number of trailing zeroes of **A**.

Reversing the above map in straightforward. For a *positive* integer **k**, we factorize it uniquely as the product of consecutive prime powers **n = p<sub>0</sub><sup>α<sub>0</sub></sup>p<sub>1</sub><sup>α<sub>1</sub></sup>⋯p<sub>n</sub><sup>α<sub>n</sub></sup>**, where **α<sub>n</sub> > 0**, then reconstruct the list as **[α<sub>1</sub>, ⋯, α<sub>n</sub>]**, appending **α<sub>0</sub>** zeroes.

### How it works

#### List to integer

```
TṪạL;³ÆẸ  Main link. Argument: A (list of non-negative integers)

T         Yield all indices of A that correspond to truthy (i.e., non-zero) items.
 Ṫ        Tail; select the last truthy index.
          This returns 0 if the list is empty.
   L      Yield the length of A.
  ạ       Compute the absolute difference of the last truthy index and the length.
          This yields the amount of trailing zeroes of A.
    ;³    Prepend the difference to A.
      ÆẸ  Convert the list from prime exponents to integer.
```

#### Integer to list

```
ÆE©Ḣ0ẋ®;  Main link. Input: k (positive integer)

ÆE        Convert k to the list of its prime exponents.
  ©       Save the list of prime exponents in the register.
   Ḣ      Head; pop the first exponent.
          If the list is empty, this yields 0.
    0ẋ    Construct a list of that many zeroes.
      ®;  Concatenate the popped list of exponents with the list of zeroes.
```

### Example output

The first one hundred positive integers map to the following lists.

```
  1: []
  2: [0]
  3: [1]
  4: [0, 0]
  5: [0, 1]
  6: [1, 0]
  7: [0, 0, 1]
  8: [0, 0, 0]
  9: [2]
 10: [0, 1, 0]
 11: [0, 0, 0, 1]
 12: [1, 0, 0]
 13: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 14: [0, 0, 1, 0]
 15: [1, 1]
 16: [0, 0, 0, 0]
 17: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 18: [2, 0]
 19: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 20: [0, 1, 0, 0]
 21: [1, 0, 1]
 22: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
 23: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 24: [1, 0, 0, 0]
 25: [0, 2]
 26: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
 27: [3]
 28: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
 29: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 30: [1, 1, 0]
 31: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 32: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 33: [1, 0, 0, 1]
 34: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
 35: [0, 1, 1]
 36: [2, 0, 0]
 37: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 38: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
 39: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 40: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
 41: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 42: [1, 0, 1, 0]
 43: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 44: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
 45: [2, 1]
 46: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
 47: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 48: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 49: [0, 0, 2]
 50: [0, 2, 0]
 51: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 52: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
 53: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 54: [3, 0]
 55: [0, 1, 0, 1]
 56: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
 57: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 58: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
 59: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 60: [1, 1, 0, 0]
 61: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 62: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
 63: [2, 0, 1]
 64: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 65: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
 66: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
 67: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 68: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
 69: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 70: [0, 1, 1, 0]
 71: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 72: [2, 0, 0, 0]
 73: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 74: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
 75: [1, 2]
 76: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
 77: [0, 0, 1, 1]
 78: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
 79: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 80: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 81: [4]
 82: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
 83: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 84: [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
 85: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 86: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
 87: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 88: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
 89: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 90: [2, 1, 0]
 91: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
 92: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
 93: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 94: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
 95: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 96: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 97: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 98: [0, 0, 2, 0]
 99: [2, 0, 0, 1]
100: [0, 2, 0, 0]
```

Comment: This is brilliant.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

### Encode, <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
2Bṁx‘Ḅ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/I6eHOxopHDTMe7mj5//9/tIGOoY6JjqWOoZmOkamOsZmOiaWOmYmOhaGOoYFBLAA)

### Decode, 6 bytes

```
ȯIBŒɠ’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxDUJRDMRWyiW5JNfSMQgN@gvQMQMdHRswBRKswSKPL0pLts@nbbus9X4eD6/b5/G93tdaMPNQQAl6t8/UpEPyKoBBaxUrsiLaMZ2TjL0iIts0liT2x45ilIQiwzKpaJvq/AuwrglNC9mEfg)

Encodes positive integers in the run lengths of the binary representation. Since we may have zeros, we increment all numbers. For example, the list `[0,1,4]` is encoded as 10011111 in binary.

Numbers from 0 to 100 ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Eek@no5NOLnjUMPO/oYHB0d06h9uPTnq4c8ajpjXHuoCE@///AA)):

```
0                     []                   
1                     [0]                  
2                     [0, 0]               
3                     [1]                  
4                     [0, 1]               
5                     [0, 0, 0]            
6                     [1, 0]               
7                     [2]                  
8                     [0, 2]               
9                     [0, 1, 0]            
10                    [0, 0, 0, 0]         
11                    [0, 0, 1]            
12                    [1, 1]               
13                    [1, 0, 0]            
14                    [2, 0]               
15                    [3]                  
16                    [0, 3]               
17                    [0, 2, 0]            
18                    [0, 1, 0, 0]         
19                    [0, 1, 1]            
20                    [0, 0, 0, 1]         
21                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      
22                    [0, 0, 1, 0]         
23                    [0, 0, 2]            
24                    [1, 2]               
25                    [1, 1, 0]            
26                    [1, 0, 0, 0]         
27                    [1, 0, 1]            
28                    [2, 1]               
29                    [2, 0, 0]            
30                    [3, 0]               
31                    [4]                  
32                    [0, 4]               
33                    [0, 3, 0]            
34                    [0, 2, 0, 0]         
35                    [0, 2, 1]            
36                    [0, 1, 0, 1]         
37                    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]      
38                    [0, 1, 1, 0]         
39                    [0, 1, 2]            
40                    [0, 0, 0, 2]         
41                    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]      
42                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]   
43                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]      
44                    [0, 0, 1, 1]         
45                    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]      
46                    [0, 0, 2, 0]         
47                    [0, 0, 3]            
48                    [1, 3]               
49                    [1, 2, 0]            
50                    [1, 1, 0, 0]         
51                    [1, 1, 1]            
52                    [1, 0, 0, 1]         
53                    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]      
54                    [1, 0, 1, 0]         
55                    [1, 0, 2]            
56                    [2, 2]               
57                    [2, 1, 0]            
58                    [2, 0, 0, 0]         
59                    [2, 0, 1]            
60                    [3, 1]               
61                    [3, 0, 0]            
62                    [4, 0]               
63                    [5]                  
64                    [0, 5]               
65                    [0, 4, 0]            
66                    [0, 3, 0, 0]         
67                    [0, 3, 1]            
68                    [0, 2, 0, 1]         
69                    [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]      
70                    [0, 2, 1, 0]         
71                    [0, 2, 2]            
72                    [0, 1, 0, 2]         
73                    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]      
74                    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]   
75                    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]      
76                    [0, 1, 1, 1]         
77                    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]      
78                    [0, 1, 2, 0]         
79                    [0, 1, 3]            
80                    [0, 0, 0, 3]         
81                    [0, 0, 0, 2, 0]      
82                    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]   
83                    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]      
84                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]   
85                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
86                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]   
87                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 2]      
88                    [0, 0, 1, 2]         
89                    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]      
90                    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]   
91                    [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]      
92                    [0, 0, 2, 1]         
93                    [0, 0, 2, 0, 0]      
94                    [0, 0, 3, 0]         
95                    [0, 0, 4]            
96                    [1, 4]               
97                    [1, 3, 0]            
98                    [1, 2, 0, 0]         
99                    [1, 2, 1]            
100                   [1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 88 bytes

```py
d=lambda n:map(len,bin(n).split('1')[1:])
e=lambda l:int('1'.join(a*'0'for a in[2]+l),2)
```

Demo:

```
>>> for i in range(33):
...     print e(d(i)), d(i)
... 
0 []
1 [0]
2 [1]
3 [0, 0]
4 [2]
5 [1, 0]
6 [0, 1]
7 [0, 0, 0]
8 [3]
9 [2, 0]
10 [1, 1]
11 [1, 0, 0]
12 [0, 2]
13 [0, 1, 0]
14 [0, 0, 1]
15 [0, 0, 0, 0]
16 [4]
17 [3, 0]
18 [2, 1]
19 [2, 0, 0]
20 [1, 2]
21 [1, 1, 0]
22 [1, 0, 1]
23 [1, 0, 0, 0]
24 [0, 3]
25 [0, 2, 0]
26 [0, 1, 1]
27 [0, 1, 0, 0]
28 [0, 0, 2]
29 [0, 0, 1, 0]
30 [0, 0, 0, 1]
31 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
32 [5]
```

## Python 2, 130 bytes

Here’s a more “efficient” solution where the bit-length of the output is linear in the bit-length of the input rather than exponential.

```py
def d(n):m=-(n^-n);return d(n/m/m)+[n/m%m+m-2]if n else[]
e=lambda l:int('0'+''.join(bin(2*a+5<<len(bin(a+2))-4)[3:]for a in l),2)
```

Comment: Uses the same algorithm as [my solution](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=29370373#29370373) :)

Comment: @KennyLau: I hadn’t looked at your solution. They look similar but not identical (0s and 1s are swapped). And yours fails to round-trip the empty list.

Comment: I see, thanks for reminding.

Comment: By the way, I said the output can be in ***any*** base.

Comment: Since sharing code between the functions is allowed, it looks like you can just build `e` to be the inverse for `d`: `e=lambda l,i=0:l!=d(i)and-~e(l,i+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <strike>204</strike> 202 bytes

```
p=lambda x,y:(2*y+1<<x)-1
u=lambda n,x=0:-~n%2<1and u(-~n//2-1,x+1)or[x,n//2]
e=lambda l:l and-~reduce(p,l,len(l)-1)or 0
def d(n):
 if n<1:return[]
 r=[];n,l=u(n-1);exec"n,e=u(n);r=[e]+r;"*l;return[n]+r
```

Works by repeatedly applying a Z+ x Z+ <-> Z+ bijection, prepended by the list length.

```
0: []
1: [0]
2: [1]
3: [0, 0]
4: [2]
5: [0, 0, 0]
6: [1, 0]
7: [0, 0, 0, 0]
8: [3]
9: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
10: [1, 0, 0]
11: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
12: [0, 1]
13: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
14: [1, 0, 0, 0]
15: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
16: [4]
17: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
18: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
19: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
20: [0, 0, 1]
21: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
22: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
23: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
24: [2, 0]
25: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
26: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
27: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
28: [0, 0, 0, 1]
29: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
30: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
31: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: One question: which function is the "list to integer" function, and which is the "integer to list" function?

Comment: @zyabin101 `e` is list to integer, `d` is integer to list (encode/decode).

Comment: I like this solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Retina, 17 + 23 = 40 bytes

From list to integer:

```
\d+
$&$*0
^
1
 
1
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQrCiQmJCowCl4KMQogCjE&input=MCAxIDIgMyAwIDUgMA)

From integer to list:

```
^1

S`1
m`^(0*)
$.1
¶
<space>
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XjEKClNgMQptYF4oMCopCiQuMQrCtgog&input=MTEwMTAwMTAwMDExMDAwMDAx)

Uses [Kaseorg's Algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78989/48934).

Comment: [16 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/zpCLKzjBkEvVN8GA69A2LoX//w0NDQwNQMjAEEQAKQA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online").

Comment: [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fUMNAS5NLQUXPkCtOgQvINzQwNAAhA0MQAaQA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online").

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 87 bytes

```
F=n=>n.toString(2).split(1).slice(1).map(_=>_.length)
G=a=>g=(i=0)=>F(i)+''==a?i:g(++i)
```

`G` goes through all inputs since it's shorter